Is this hosewinder broken?
I can't seem to plug a hose into this part of this hosewinder/hosereel I bought used..
Is it because it's broken? Neither male or female will fit in there.
Video: https://streamable.com/ockjar

If a male hose end will not thread in there, it is broken.

You need a male end to fit.  Most garden hose male ends should fit.  They are mainly standard size.  Cannot see the threads inside well enough to see if they are stripped or not.  Some hosewinders might for a strange reason, usually their own connection type, but they do supply it.  It would come with the winder, but will need to contact the company for replacement.
